# Must sambaAcctFlags have 11 characters?

Tags: samba, ldap, openldap

Still going through my LDAP database in my search for the wicked, I noticed a lot of accounts have `sambaAcctFlags` equal to `[U]`, though the Samba docs says it should have 11 characters between `[` and `]` (and some actually do).

Is that a problem, or is 11 characters just an upper limit?

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, many entries are like this:

```
sambaAcctFlags: [U          ]
```

But some are like this:

```
sambaAcctFlags: [U]
```

It is the later I'm concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

According to the passdb documentation on [Samba.org](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/passdb.html), *the account flag field can contain up to 16 characters. Presently, only 11 are in use*.

I can confirm that we've been using it in production for many years with accounts having just one flag.

Comment: Not much a question of having one flag, but of the field being filled with spaces to make up 11 characters or not. I hadn't noticed that section (I was looking up the field name), so that's +1. I don't feel, however, confident that there's a definitive answer. Sure, it _works_ here, but that doesn't mean it may not cause subtle problems.